# Generic interface inferring type from object property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I've got an interface `I` with the goal of making sure that the property type of `val` is the same as the return type of `fn`.

The type in question is restricted to `string` or `number`.

```
interface I<T extends string | number> {
  val: T;
  fn: () => T;
}

const x1: I<string> = {
  val: "hello",
  fn: () => "world",
};

const x2: I<number> = {
  val: 3,
  fn: () => 4,
};
```

Is it somehow possible to not having to explicitly set `T` and rather infer it? So that I could just do:

```
// accepted
const x1: I = {
  val: "hello",
  fn: () => "world",
};

// accepted
const x2: I = {
  val: 3,
  fn: () => 4,
};

// rejected
const x3: I = {
  val: "hello",
  fn: () => 4,
};

// rejected
const x4: I = {
  val: 3,
  fn: () => "world",
};
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent `string | number` itself?  If I write `{val: 3, fn: ()=>"world"}`, should it be accepted or rejected?

Comment: @jcalz Hi! I clarified my quesiton. If the types don't match it should be rejected.

Comment: So maybe you want a union instead of generics, then, since that behaves the way you want, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8B4dm) or [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlLDGN).  Does that meet your needs or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz I tried making a readable example, but it probably wasn't great. I can try to re-do tomorrow in hope of improving it.

I'd like to force the return type of `fn` to match `val`, where `val` could be whatever TS type (I tried to simplify by having the union `string | number`).

I was just trying to find out if there was a way to "connect" `val` and `fn` so that the type would be "read/inferred" from `val` for example and enforced as output of `fn`.

Comment: There's no way to ask the compiler to infer a type argument for a generic type; the proposal in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) *might* do that, if implemented, like `I<infer>`, but for now it's not part of the language.  In order to get behavior like it you'd need a generic helper function, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqe9rm). Does that meet your needs now or am I still missing something?

Comment: @jcalz That's exactly what I'd need! Sorry for being unclear in my question. Let me know if I could improve it somehow. I was trying to keep it focused on the core thing, but I guess I cut away too much details. Your answer has better typing than the one from Tanek, so maybe post yours as an answer? 

For the `asI`, at least I could use a bit of explanation of it. U extends T, but T and U also exists inside the "type destructuring". Hm. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible for TS to infer the type for your example. However, there is a way to achieve similar effects using a helper function:

```
function make<T extends string|number>(input: I<T>) {
  return input;
}

// accepted
const x1 = make({
  val: "hello",
  fn: () => "world",
});

// accepted
const x2 = make({
  val: 3,
  fn: () => 4,
});

// rejected
const x3 = make({
  val: "hello",
  fn: () => 4,
});

// rejected
const x4 = make({
  val: 3,
  fn: () => "world",
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIB4AqyIA9IgAmAzssWFKAObIA+yIArgLYBG0AfMgN4BQyyAG5wANgC5kmANz9kMEBIAUASmQBeLtN4BfXrxiMQCMMAD2IZMzgBrCFhz4IRUuUogqtJm06LQAB0YwCQxMDlU+ASgIMEYoC39AmV1eAHoU5EQkP0hCXgRzcmRcAEZ1SxsIRQihUQkAIgALCBERUzqAGll5JVUNZDqAd1MoEUIOnWUZVPTMiGyIXPyQQtwAJjKrWyrZYXFkAGZOgW7kFXUuABZO7Um9NOQogCsIYwW8grAi-Y2K7YFd+pNFptI5yBSnXqXa63aYPCDPV6LD5FC4-LbVAEHUEnM59QbDUbjG5SIA)